# Parse: Remove row in custom class

Tags: objective-c, parse-platform

I am trying to remove a row in a custom class with the following code. For some reason it is not deleting it from the database.

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        for (Friends *currentFriend in objects) {
            [currentFriend deleteInBackground];
        }
    }];
```

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you checking what the query returns and the status returned by the deletion?

Comment: I'm trying to delete the object the query returns from the custom class.

Comment: I'm aware of that, doesn't change my question - have you done any debugging...

Comment: Oh, no I don't know how to.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
[currentFriend deleteInBackground];
```

For

```
[currentFriend deleteInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
if (succeeded) {

}
```